# Update items dynamically in toolbar of navigation controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have navigation controller with toolbar. Toolbar contains a segmented control with three items. When user select one of the segment in this control, I need to update toolbar and add to it additional item. 
I tried next code in viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setToolbarItems:items_array];
}
```

and in didChangeSegmentControl event handler:

```
-(void)didChangeSegmentControl:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {
    NSArray* items = [self currentToolbarItems];
    [self setToolbarItems: items];
}
```

But after changing toolbar items in didChangeSegmentControl they are disappeared.
How is it possible to update items of toolbar not in viewDidLoad method?

Comment: Are you sure there are items in `currentToolbarItems`?  It sounds like it is empty, which would be why it removes the items from the toolbar

Comment: I am sure, that `currentToolbarItems` contains items, after `[self setToolbarItems: items]` count of `[self toolbarItems]` is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

It looks, that I have found answer on this question.
In [self currentToolbarItems] routine I wrap UISegmentedControl in UIBarButtonItem. When use the same UISegmentedControl twice for creating UIBarButtonItem and assign it to toolbar items, toolbar doesn't show it. 
So, instead of creating UIBarButtonItem every time with same control, I re-use it.

Comment: I was banging my head against this issue for an hour this morning and your answer solved the problem.

Comment: I have not tried your method yet and can't wait to get home to do it. I have this problem which hopefully your method will solve.

In my viewdidappear, I add an ivar uislider > uibuttonitem > navigation.toolbar. it all works. but after I bring up a modal view (ie MFMailViewComposer) and dismiss it, my slider disappears. WOOOT ? I found out that after the dismiss modal, my views viewdidappear gets called again, and obviously I add the ivar uislider again to a new uibuttonitem and set it in the navigation.toolbar. Now instead of having an ivar uislider, i should have an ivar uibuttonitem too.